# Selecting just some rows of a RGList

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using the package Limma to analyse some data. After reading the raw data with `read.maimagenes` I get a `RGList` object. R.cut and G.cut are a value of class numeric and I want the values above them. I tried something like this:

```
RG$R <- RG$R[RG$R>R.cut] 
RG$G <- RG$G[RG$G>G.cut]
```

But this converts the class of RG$R from matrix to numeric how could I keep the matrix class (I don't know if introducing some NA values would affect the rest of the analyse).  I have tried subset like this:

```
RG.probe$R <- subset(x=RG, subset=RG$R>R.cut)
```

But it keeps returning an error `Error: Two subscripts required`

How can this be done?

Aside: If I would like to just get the rows that are above the R.cut and G.cut?

**Possible solution:**
I have found that with `ifelse` I can do it although I must introduce a value for the ones that are under the cut, and I haven't found the way to check if both R and G channels are above each cut.

```
RG$R<-ifelse(RG$R>R.cut, RG$R, '')
RG$G<-ifelse(RG$G>G.cut, RG$G, '')
```

Although it is converted to character, and therefore I cannot do further analysis.

**Data to make it reproducible:**

```
library(limma)
RG<-read.maimages(path, source='agilent')
class(RG)
[1] "RGList"
attr(,"package")
[1] "limma"
dput(head(RG$R))
structure(c(2893, 81.5, 80.5, 140208, 4512, 6272, 4934, 195, 
184.5, 164092, 11819, 10569, 1689.5, 83, 82, 68996, 2260.5, 3603, 
2470, 84, 77, 96750, 3203, 5223, 3246, 85.5, 104.5, 54773, 519.5, 
8244.5, 1807, 86.5, 88, 204574, 15693, 8939.5, 2040, 87, 95, 
131880, 7346, 9922.5, 1445, 76, 85.5, 125598, 3863, 5758.5, 2626, 
87.5, 85, 180266, 18173, 20171.5, 1811.5, 84, 87.5, 122498, 3993, 
5857, 1799, 87.5, 82, 123220, 3780, 5964, 1706, 77.5, 80, 124463, 
3390, 5070, 3787, 81.5, 88, 65874, 269, 781.5, 1476, 90, 89, 
122445, 4232, 6479, 2788, 82, 87.5, 80669, 791, 7440.5, 1503, 
81, 88, 124702, 4270, 6111, 2012.5, 93.5, 90, 215820, 4555, 3101, 
1727.5, 102, 109, 131316, 4284, 6638, 2009, 95.5, 111.5, 175474, 
12665, 17213, 1532, 87.5, 84.5, 117568, 4098, 6100, 1436, 83, 
91, 118472, 4067.5, 6114, 1651.5, 83, 82, 127308, 4150, 6277, 
2028.5, 85.5, 89, 74816, 896.5, 7697, 2698, 84, 92.5, 99431, 
1273, 9182.5, 1833.5, 100, 104, 163604, 15582, 12146, 2359, 102, 
109, 159301, 17229, 9822.5, 1857, 86, 88, 130319, 4354.5, 6266.5, 
1887, 87, 87, 133386, 11639.5, 8931, 2304.5, 86.5, 87, 91022, 
1011, 14524, 1353, 84, 88, 114282, 3935, 5944, 1487, 83, 87, 
125507, 4138, 5804, 3379, 86.5, 88, 63703.5, 331, 1167, 1778, 
87, 83.5, 123988, 4366, 6670, 1862, 94.5, 92, 134174, 4558, 6881, 
2388.5, 82, 91.5, 174744, 8570, 10677, 4374, 94, 94, 179579, 
12753, 10869, 3747.5, 115, 144.5, 133809, 3710, 5406, 5062, 93.5, 
92, 207843, 13220, 6774, 3294, 78, 82.5, 149764, 3774, 5582, 
5303, 93, 100, 93479.5, 803, 6709, 2969, 86.5, 101, 149011, 4043, 
5407, 5488, 106, 118.5, 191053, 9990.5, 12194, 4308, 89, 85, 
143087, 3926.5, 5370.5, 5168, 87, 91.5, 137415, 4028, 5671, 4649.5, 
91, 90, 147328, 4102, 5614.5, 7225, 87, 85, 179052, 15612, 16908, 
5815.5, 84, 88, 200883, 13229, 11482, 3551, 101, 125, 224012, 
20461, 16149.5, 3992, 98, 83, 134744, 3569, 5068, 4817, 97, 92, 
142087, 4203, 5678, 5436, 108, 84.5, 195104, 11299, 13246), .Dim = c(6L, 
51L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", 
"US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1",     "US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3",     "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", "US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", 
"US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", "US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1",     "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3",     "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1",     "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3",     "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3",     "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1",     "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3",     "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4"
)))
dput(head(RG$G))
structure(c(2324, 58, 52, 98015, 9800, 5284, 1472, 114, 92.5, 
27879, 2296, 3272.5, 3637, 216, 204.5, 34898, 731, 5084, 3466, 
77, 74, 32543, 497, 7416, 1344, 79.5, 99, 52753, 2363, 3457, 
686, 39, 44.5, 32866, 2937, 4324, 910, 42, 40, 42361, 2780, 4072, 
1587, 83.5, 97, 79659, 7667, 10103, 754, 49.5, 44, 23664, 2962, 
4166, 1390.5, 136, 156.5, 70132.5, 7914, 4876, 1609, 99, 125, 
25923.5, 610, 5125, 1526, 198.5, 157, 94640.5, 10408, 9233, 1060, 
42, 37, 70033, 3144, 4355.5, 1465, 89, 91, 99188, 9587, 7547, 
743, 61.5, 60, 65888, 3247, 4676.5, 1931.5, 89, 84, 65967, 11226, 
7757, 873.5, 56, 66, 20126.5, 3291, 4736, 1339.5, 298, 300, 75324, 
6712, 8500, 894, 65, 86, 26341.5, 3132.5, 4647, 2372, 80, 81.5, 
73418.5, 5026, 7612, 1564, 70, 73, 77180, 7802.5, 9454, 1315, 
90, 85, 20562, 340, 5337, 868.5, 49, 55, 64712.5, 2947, 4260, 
798, 46, 48, 52505, 3380, 4663.5, 904, 69.5, 80, 33371.5, 3300, 
4997, 813, 73, 81, 29552, 2932, 4632.5, 1696.5, 187, 324, 63647, 
6407, 8571.5, 872, 39.5, 52, 24518, 3094, 4387, 752.5, 54, 52, 
48299.5, 3221, 4278, 2631, 61, 72, 27229, 513, 5019, 1256.5, 
61, 63, 74560, 11016, 9019, 942, 57, 55, 70933.5, 3526.5, 5383, 
1457.5, 162, 193.5, 86276, 8154, 12084, 1590, 213, 293, 66871, 
6580, 9535, 833.5, 57, 62.5, 36416, 3229, 4600, 2161.5, 53.5, 
42.5, 39157.5, 2952, 3977, 3481, 67, 68, 18675, 152, 536, 1977, 
57, 55.5, 32861, 2785, 3812, 4739.5, 112.5, 113.5, 104923, 6231, 
8198, 1907, 57.5, 69, 76674.5, 3219, 4244, 3879.5, 183.5, 171, 
110822, 9582, 8426, 1746, 74.5, 74, 33327, 2774, 4017, 3333, 
187, 270.5, 83696, 6616, 7080, 4737, 38, 37, 30041, 429.5, 3970, 
3347, 45, 46, 106822, 8003.5, 7137.5, 2431, 32, 35, 32985, 3121, 
4179, 2535.5, 28, 34, 36131.5, 3135, 4126, 1929, 42, 65, 47428, 
3300, 4626.5, 5371, 54.5, 43.5, 108175, 9983, 6182, 5139.5, 34, 
28, 26774, 152, 518, 2621, 48, 32, 44499, 3409, 4643), .Dim = c(6L, 
51L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", 
"US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3",     "US23502326_253482110017_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110027_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", "US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", 
"US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", "US23502326_253482110028_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110029_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110030_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1", "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3",     "US23502326_253482110031_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_1",     "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_2", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_3", "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_1_4", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_1", "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_2", 
"US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_3", "US23502326_253482110049_S01_GE2_1105_Oct12_2_4"
)))
```

From the dput you can create an RGList by `new("RGList")` I know it is to much data but as I previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767253/how-to-short-the-length-of-dput) I don't know how to short the output.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Thanks.

Comment: Done, I added also some clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that finally I got is doing almost the same:

```
RG$G <- ifelse(RG$R>R.cut, RG$G, NA)
RG$R <- ifelse(RG$G>G.cut, RG$R, NA)
```

Deleting this values seems to increase the Fold Change of each gene as already happened comparing the original RG with the RG with deleted values as in the question.